# You must set myJID before calling connect error

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to implement 'OpenFire' server for chat application. I got source code on git at https://github.com/rayaleen/OpenFireClient.
 On login button action it shows me following error:

```
Error connecting: Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=2 "You must set myJID before calling connect." UserInfo=0x7a87c80 {NSLocalizedDescription=You must set myJID before calling connect.}
```

But I could not find any document to implement this. Does any one have any idea about this type of error? Any link for documentation would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

if u r using the XMPPFramework for ios, you can find a class named XMPPJID and XMPPStream.
I am sure u had called the XMPPStream's instance  method "connect" that caused what u said.
There for u can search for which variable actually the instance is ,for example it named 'aSteam',and then search ur whole project for  the sentence 'aSteam connect'.
If success ,what u need is to add one line before it connet.it should be

```
[aSteam setMyJID:[XMPPJID JIDWithString:@"yourname@domain.com/resouse"]]
```

if u don't know what JID means please search for XMPP's relative documents.

> But I could not find any document to implement this.

just saw it,if u can't find the introductions,i can give you the demo I wrote ,and the server also setup by myself.if need

Comment: Hello Reese, Thanks for your help. Please give me demo that you wrote. That would be great help.

Comment: do u mind that the UI is in chinese? u can download it at this url:http://code4app.com/ios/5206fc076803faed58000000  my server often open during Beijing time 9 AM-18PM.if've reading issues contact 109327402@qq.com i can translater englisth version for you

Comment: Thanks Reese for your grat help.

Answer (score 0):

If I used this code ,On login button action it shows me following error:

```
self.jid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",self.username,self.host];
//[_xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:_jid resource:@"drrr"]];
```

so I change this to my project,so it is normal,I hope it works for you

```
[_xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:self.username]];
```